# PHP: Splitting a large string by certain characters in as large chunks as possible

Tags: php, regex

I am implementing Google Translation API and it will only take up to 5000 characters at a time, so I need to split larger documents into smaller ones and send multiple API requests.

I need to therefore split my content into chunks that are as long as possible (but less than 5000) and that has been split, hopefully not in the middle of a sentence which would make the translations difficult to process for Google.

I would therefore like to give my method an array of characters it should look for when splitting.

- `</div>`
- `</p>`
- `</section>`
- `</blockquote>`
- `</br>`
- `.` (dot space)

What would be a good approach to this?

Comment: Using DOM is better approach instead of regex while parsing HTML

Comment: I am not sure the document contains any HTML. In fact it is likely to be just plain text.

Comment: @SørenBeckJensen what do you think `</div>` is then?!?

Comment: IF the tag is there, THEN use it. But there is not guarantee that there will be any DOM tags.

Answer (score 2):

Regexp is greedy by default.

```
.{0,4980}(\<\/div\>|\<\/p\>|\<\/section\>|\<\/blockquote\>|\<\/br\>|\.\s)
```

Should give the longest string ending with one of your delimiters.

Comment: PHP (And RegEx Buddy) does not seem to support the [0,4980] part of the regex?

Comment: `[]` are character classes, `{}` are for ranges. `*` is incorrect there as well should be `.{0,4980}`. The `*` is a quantifier meaning 0 or more of the previous character.